# Tweak Content Editor treeview in Sitecore

Tags: treeview, sitecore

Today I saw a demonstration of the episerver cms and it had a few features that I really liked.

One was that items in the treview on the left that had no version for the current language was shown in an *italic font*.

It shouldn't be to hard to implement this into Sitecore, anyone got any ideas?

BR Larre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sitecore 6 we've added a an information-action panel to the left of the tree. We call it Quick Action Bar.

One of the default examples is that you can see an icon warning you that the item will not be visible on the website, because it's not published.

Quick Action Bar is pluggable, so you can create your own warning that will display an icon if the item doesn't have a version in the current language. You can also add related actions, so that you can click on the icon an maybe create a version right there.

Take a look at [Client Configuration Cookbook at SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Client%20Configuration%20Cookbook.aspx) for related docs.

It's also possible to change item styles to make item name use italics in tree, but it's not as easily pluggable for dynamic scenarios like yours.

Comment: That seams like a perfect solution, Thank you Alexey. I am a big fan of your blog by the way it is one of the first sources I search when I'm stuck.